# CURL status returns internal server error 500

Tags: php, curl

Im trying to implement a bitcoin gateway from apirone. The problem is that when i run the CURL function it returns an internal server error 500.

so i tried to run their demo code. although it works fine on their site, it return the same internal server error i i try it on my server. Below is the code

```
<?php
  $json_data = array (
    'type' => "forwarding",
    'currency' => "btc",
    'callback' => array(
        'url'=> "http://example.com/callback",
        'data' => array (
            'invoice_id' => "1234"
        )
    ),
    'destinations' => array (        
        array('address' => "1apiKcJM95jENZeom2dQo8ShK7dUQkRaS", 'amount' => 40330),
        array('address' => "1ApiwpetcWnBbkpU7cb7biPfc6Tiucasf8", 'amount' => 40330)
    )
  );
  
  $api_endpoint = "https://apirone.com/api/v2/wallet";
 
  $curl = curl_init($api_endpoint);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json_data));
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $http_status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
  curl_close($curl);
 
  if ($http_status_code==200){
      $decoded = json_decode($response, true);
      echo "Wallet: " . $decoded["wallet"] . "<BR>";
      echo "Key: " . $decoded["transfer_key"];
  } else {
      var_dump($response);
  }
?>
```

more details can be found here https://apirone.com/docs/forwarding-wallet

can someone let me know what might be causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: So what are the logs saying?

Comment: @TonyStark it doesnt log any errors related to this.. Only a few undifined varaibles are logged from other pages

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a cURL settings issue.

Try placing

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
```

after the

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($json_data));
```

Also, I wouldn't `json_encode($json_data)` directly in the function argument. Try encoding it before and send the already encoded json in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` option.